# How to use print_r of PHP in browser

Tags: php

I am using this php script for predictionIO. The print_r php function works well in terminal & prints the array corresponding to user 1 & num 4. Now i want to run the script in browser & print similar result(right now nothing is shown in browser using this PHP script)

```
<?php
require_once("/home/deepak/vendor/autoload.php");

use predictionio\EngineClient;
$engineClient = new EngineClient('http://192.168.1.13:8000');
$response = $engineClient->sendQuery(array("user"=>"1", "num"=>4));

print_r($response);
echo '$response';
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried before asking this question? Have you tried `echo $response;` (without the simple quotes because you want to echo the value of a variable and not the string "$response")?

Comment: Are you opening the file through a web-server, does the address start with `http...`?

Comment: The "sendQuery" function is not working in the php script in browser(if i echo "Something"; on next line it won't be shown) but it works fine in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your echo will work because you've put it into quotes. Try it without

```
echo $response;
```

To get the print_r to print to the screen and be formatted try wrapping it in these:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';
```

You could try using

```
var_dump($response);
```

Just to see if it will print to the screen.